# PDF generation with phantomJS - is it possible to make phantomJS read from a stream instead of an URL address?

Tags: node.js, stream, pdf-generation, phantomjs

When it comes to generation of bigger files, it's hard to use the usual approach - save html to file, then pass it to phantomJS read it again and then make the conversion. I've tried it in my I3 4Gb RAM machine and a ~600Mb file conversion eats up all swap AND memory avaible and then phantomJS crashes.
So, I guess I need a way to stream the data directly to phantomJS, like this:

```
    Datasource -> phantomJS -> http socket
```

But I couldn't find a way to stream to phantomJS. Any ideas?
BTW, I'm using nodeJS.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, PhantomJS doesn't support streamed pages in this way.

Comment: I highly doubt, any browser does, but since PhantomJS is open-source, you can tinker with it and adjust it so that it supports streaming rendering. This will be very hard.

Comment: My bad, guys. I was reading the documentation of the phantomJS wrapper for node (https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantom) and came across with: "No really, how does it work?
I will answer that question with a question. How do you communicate with a process that doesn't support shared memory, sockets, FIFOs, or standard input?"